# While executing following query getting error message

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT o.TypeAbv + ' (' + o.TypeCode + ')' AS 'Type', o.PracticeAbv + ' (' + o.PracticeCode + ')' 
AS 'Practice', b.Unit AS 'Unit #', o.Acres AS 'Acres', o.InsuredSharePct AS 'Share', o.ApprovedYield 
AS 'Approved Yield', o.AdjustedYield AS 'Adjusted Yield', o.ProdGuarantee AS 'Guar/Acre', o.RateYield 
AS 'Simple Avg Yield', 
(CAST((CASE WHEN o.ProdGuarantee = '' THEN Null ELSE o.ProdGuarantee END) as decimal(10,2)) * CAST(o.Acres as decimal(10,2))) 
AS 'Total Guar UOM', o.BasePrice AS 'Price', o.Liability AS 'Total Protection', o.UnitDiscountFactor 
AS 'Unit Disc Factor', o.TotalPremium AS 'Base Premium', o.ProdPremium AS 'Subsidy Premium', o.Subsidy 
AS 'Subsidy Amount', o.SubsidyPercent AS 'Subsidy %', o.PremiumRate AS 'Base Prem Rate' 
FROM RMA_Output o INNER JOIN AR_Premium_Baseline b ON b.TestCaseID = o.TestCaseID 
AND b.ModuleNumber = o.ModuleNumber AND b.CropLineNumber = o.CropLineNumber AND b.ARLineNumber = o.ARLineNumber 
WHERE o.TestCaseID = 'AR_CA_Sacmnto_Chry_ARH_FeeByGrp_OuBuElection_MP4006' AND o.ModuleNumber = 4 AND o.CropLineNumber = 1 
AND o.CropYear = 2018
ORDER BY b.Unit, o.PracticeCode, o.TypeAbv
```

> error message : Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 32 Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Anybody have a fix?.

Comment: From the error message, I'm guessing that is SQL Server. Please tag that next time. You may also try and reduce the amount of code you are sharing. That is pretty heavyweight for your problem.

Comment: More than likely you have a string in one of those fields you are casting that cannot be converted to a number. You would do well to reformat your code with indents and one field / condition per line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the only line where you are doing some conversion.

```
 ,(CAST((CASE WHEN o.ProdGuarantee = '' THEN Null ELSE o.ProdGuarantee END) as decimal(10,2)) * CAST(o.Acres as decimal(10,2))) AS 'Total Guar UOM'
```

If 2012+, use **TRY_CONVERT()**

```
 ,try_convert(decimal(10,2),o.ProdGuarantee) * try_convert(decimal(10,2),o.Acres) AS 'Total Guar UOM'
```

Try_Convert() will return a NULL if the conversion fails, and NOT throw an error.

Comment: @S.Shah  Happy it helped.  If so inclined, take a moment to ACCEPT the answer :)